# Why is a single product page not loading in Django project

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I am trying to make an ecommerce project and I already set up products page, but It should load a product description page after goint to api/products/2 page, example(2 is a product id).
views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = None
    for i in products:
        if i['_id'] == pk:
            product = i
            break

    return Response(product)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getRoutes, name="routes"),
    path('products/', views.getProducts, name="products"),
    path('prodcucts/<str:pk>/', views.getProduct, name="product"),
]
```

**I already tried int:pk instead of str:pk**

Comment: Can you also share your model?

Comment: it's a file with static data:`products = [
    {
      '_id': '1',
      'name': 'Airpods Wireless Bluetooth Headphones',
      'image': '/images/airpods.jpg',
      'description':
        'Bluetooth technology lets you connect it with compatible devices wirelessly High-quality AAC audio offers immersive listening experience Built-in microphone allows you to take calls while working',
      'brand': 'Apple',
      'category': 'Electronics',
      'price': 89.99,
      'countInStock': 10,
      'rating': 4.5,
      'numReviews': 12,
    },`

Comment: Don't you have any model? And from where the `products` come from which you are iterating through?

Comment: @SunderamDubey no, but data I uploaded in comments gets loaded on products page so it should be working on a single product page, as well

Comment: So it's a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Can you please just change `<int:pk>` and `product=""` ? Then check.

Comment: Also you should only `return Response (product)` if it is in `products` otherwise it would send `None` value or either empty string, if you use `product="'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first check whether you need `<str:pk>` or `<int:pk>` as `"2"` and `2` is treated differently in Python.

Then try this:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = ""

    for i in products:
        if i['_id'] == pk:
            product = i

    return Response(Product)
```

### Edit:

The path name `path('prodcucts/<str:pk>/'...` seems incorrect kindly check it.

Comment: Tried all of that, still nothing

Comment: @Myrodis You spelling of products is incorrect here `path('prodcucts/<str:pk`  kindly check it. Are you sure the `pk` exist in `products`?

Comment: I have been trying to fix this problem since yesterday lol. Thank you.

Comment: @Myrodis Happy your problem solved, but I am interested in knowing that what solved your problem, so that I can edit the Answer with.

Comment: the only problem was spelling in urls. Although, with <int:pk> data does not get loaded, <str:pk> is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring `products = None` and then you iterate with a for loop through `products`. That results in iterating over `None`

Try to go for something like this:

```py
from .your_model_module import Product

@api_view(['GET'])
def getProduct(request, pk):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=pk)

    return Response(product)
```

First you need to import your model. Then you do a `get` query within all these Product objects that are stored in your database. The `get` query will result in an error (if not found matching object or when multiple objects are found) or will return one object.

If you want to allow that multiple objects are getting found, replace `get` with `filter` lookup.

Also stick to your `int:pk`

Comment: I tried it but didn't work. plus I do not have a classic django models file yet, it's just a file with static data.